# rw_semaphore's negative count value

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mutex, embedded-linux, semaphore

I am debugging a kernel crash dump. There seems to be a problem with one process was trying to memory map a new region. The problem is that it was not able to hold the memory map semaphore.

When I looked into process's mm_struct and printed its content. I saw that the `struct rw_semaphore mmap_sem` were as seen below. Now, does he value of `count` seem suspicious? It has a negative value, as if there was a race condition where it was decremented twice by two different threads after checking for zero.

```
  mmap_sem = {
    count = -4294967295,
    wait_lock = {
      {
        rlock = {
          raw_lock = {
            slock = 262148
          }
        }
      }
    },
    wait_list = {
      next = 0xffff8801f0113e48,
      prev = 0xffff8801f0113e48
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. I thought crash pulls the correct data types and uses that properly when printing out the all the values ...

Looks like crash utility is not read the `count` member as an `int` ....

When I print it as int, I get the correct value.

```
crash> p (int) (((struct mm_struct *) 0xffff8801f15fa540)->mmap_sem).count
$13 = 1
```